# How to use the Show Event in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, events

I try tu use this msdn snipped to execute some code right after my form loads:

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _ 
 Handles Form1.Shown
      Some Code
End Sub
```

But it seems that I am missing something. I get an errormessage that translated sounds like this:

The Handle requiere an  WithEvents-Variable, which is defined in the contained type or its basis class... My Form is named Form1 so that should be ok. the error is marked in the second line of the code. Any ideas?

Comment: @Oded: I'll have to rollback your change because I think you had just removed the error from the question ;-)

Comment: @Meta-Knight - I see... you might be right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Handles Form1.Shown
```

do this:

```
Handles Me.Shown
```

Comment: I do not have that typo in my code, still get the same message. Do I have to declare something more, and if where?

Comment: You are right, even without the typo I got the error too. Look at my edit for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Usually that is the sort of error you would get if you create the form in code and not in the designer.  The designer will automatically declare the generated form as WithEvents.  If you create the Form in code instead you have to declare it as WithEvents.

For example:

```
Public Form1 as frmMain
```

Would generate that error unless you add the handler yourself.

```
AddHandler Form1.Shown, AddressOf Form1_Shown
```

If you do this instead:

```
Public WithEvents Form1 as frmMain
```

wouldn't generate the error.

WithEvents is necessary on any object created if you want to use the handles clause in that way.